# String cannot be converted to double aaaaa

Tags: java, string

so i'm trying to read a row in a txt file (which i got working) but
when i try to find the total it gives me an error saying "total can't be 
converted to double" although i've seen examples that should work in this 
format

EDIT: i added the Double.parseDouble(input) but now i get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class AAAAA {
   public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {

    final String fileName = "classQuizzes.txt";
 //1)
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    String input;
    double total = 0;
    double num = 0;
    double count = 0;
    double average = 0;


//2) process rows    
          while (sc.hasNext()) {
             input = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(input);

   //format 2 decimal points
            DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");



   //find total
            total += Double.parseDouble(input);  //compile error on using input
            count++; 

            System.out.println(count); //test delete later
   //find average (decimal 2 points)
            System.out.println("hi");
            average = (double)total / count;
            System.out.println("Average = " + average);

//3) class statistics


         }
         System.out.println("Program created by MYNAME");
     }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping input in Double.parseDouble();

Comment: you are looping based on sc.hasNext() but then you grab nextLine(). you should change the sc.hasNext() to sc.hasNextLine() to ensure your check coincides with what you are reading which is line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
total += input;
```

is essentially the same as

```
total = String.valueOf(total) + input;
```

You cannot set total, a double, to the resultant string. Replace that line with

```
total += Double.parseDouble(input);
```